# How are segment selectors related to the address?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, memory-address, memory-segmentation

Let's say I run the following C code and get `0x7ffd385c9588`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int test = 5;
  
  printf("%p", &test);
  
  return 0;
}
```

I've heard that the logical address contains the segment selector, so does the value provided by `printf` contain it?

I thought it was embedded within the segment register part of the instruction, e.g. `ds:[0x7ffd385c9588]`, but it's said that x64 uses 48-bit addresses, which would only fit the offset and not the selector.

Comment: Modern x86 and x86-64 systems use a flat memory model; a C pointer is just the "offset" part of a `seg:off` logical address, not including a segment selector.  The offset part is 64-bit, but it has to be correctly sign-extended 48-bit.  `sizeof(void*)` is 8, not 6, in normal C implementations.

Comment: @PeterCordes Since only 48 bits of the address are actually used I assumed that the processors have a 48-bit address bus - do they use the other 16 bits for the segment selector internally instead?

Comment: No, you seem to have some fundamental misunderstanding of x86 addressing.  You set up the segment base once with `mov ds, ax` or something loading a segment base, limit, and permissions from the GDT.  All later instructions using DS like `mov eax, [rdi]` (implicitly using `[ds: rdi]`) simply use that base with the offset from the addressing-mode.  (Or in 64-bit mode, SS/CS/DS/ES bases are hardwired as 0).  The CPU has no reason to internally attach 16-bit segment selectors to offsets, only at most a 3-bit segment number to distinguish which of SS/CS/DS/ES/FS/GS should be used with this offset.

Comment: And software certainly doesn't choose to stuff far pointers into 64 bits; there's zero reason to ever use far pointers in 64-bit mode.

Comment: @VortixDev A 64 bit mode far address including segment selector is 10 bytes long.  You'll basically never see one of these.

Comment: Re "Since only 48 bits of the address are actually used I assumed that the processors have a 48-bit address bus"...  The 48 bit address size you're  referring to is the virtual address width and has nothing to do with the address bus. Physical addresses in x86-64 processors vary from 39 bits to 52 bits.

Comment: Thanks all, this has cleared a bit up. @PeterCordes On the point of the segment selector, I read on Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_memory_segmentation) that "A logical address consists of a 16-bit segment selector (supplying 13+1 address bits) and a 16-bit offset" for x86, which had me thinking that the segment selector is included in the address as well - is this not the case, or perhaps not applicable to x64? Or am I misunderstanding it?

Comment: That description from 16-bit protected mode is a bit mangled, and seems to be talking about far pointers where you load the segment selector into a segment descriptor to use with the offset.  But that's two separate steps for software.